# How do I select rows corresponding to specific combinations of column values in R?

Tags: r, dataframe, select, filter

This is my code:

```
deck <- data.frame(
suit = rep(c("D","C","H","S"), 13),
# D = ♦ Diamond, C = ♣ Club, H = ♥ Heart, S = ♠ Spade
rank = rep(2:14, 4)
# 11 = Jack, 12 = Queen, 13 = King, 14 = Ace
)
```

and my output looks like this (goes until 52)

```
> deck
suit rank
1     D    2
2     C    3
3     H    4
4     S    5
5     D    6
6     C    7
7     H    8
8     S    9
9     D   10
10    C   11
11    H   12
....
```

The excercise asks me to select specific combinations: A♦ (14 D), K♣ (13  C), Q♣ (12 C) and so on.The data is quite little so i could of course pick and choose by just looking at it but i was wondering if there is any function that would allow me to do it quicker.
I tried this

```
library(dplyr) df %>% filter_all(any_vars(. %in% c('value1', 'value2', 
...)))here
```

But it doesnt really work when looking for a specific combination because i would have to repeat it for every one.

Any suggestion is appreciated.
Cheers!

Comment: If you already know your cards, what does it mean to "pick" them out of the deck..

Answer (score 0):

Put your target cards in a frame, and merge:

```
target_cards <- data.frame(suit = c("D","C","C"),rank = c(14,13,12))

inner_join(deck,target_cards)
```

Output:

```
  suit rank
1    D   14
2    C   13
3    C   12
```

Note that since you already know your target cards, the result however, is just the same as your targets.

Comment: Thank you, this is perfect. Would you also know by any chanche how to create a logic function that is TRUE only if the cards in deck are all from target cards? I did something similar already, to see if 5 cards constitute a flush, so cards with the same suit : is.Flush <- all(hand$suit == hand$suit[1]). 
is.Flush